# error: no type named 'type' while calling static function from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Inside my generic Matrix(T) class I'm overloading operator+ using threading using a static function that adds to a single row like this:

```
    template <class T>
    static void addToRow(vector<T> &dest, const vector<T> &source, int pos, int colls)
    {
        typename vector<T>::iterator itDest = dest.begin() + pos;
        typename vector<T>::iterator itSource = source.cend() + pos;
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter != colls)
        {
            *itDest++ += *itSource++;
            ++counter;
        }
    }
```

this function is implemented outside the class.

inside the operator+ overload I'm trying to call it like this:

```
const Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &other) const
{
    Matrix<T> result(*this);
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    int i, pos;
    std::thread thrd;
    for (i = 0; i < _rows; ++i)
    {
        pos = i*_colls;
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&addToRow<T>, ref(_matrix), cref(other._matrix), pos, _colls));
    }
    typename vector<std::thread>::iterator it;
    for (it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->join();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and for the line:

```
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&addToRow<T>, std::ref(*this), _matrix, other._matrix, pos, _colls));
```

I get the error:

```
    /cygdrive/c/Users/Roy/Desktop/semester s year                 1/CPP/ex3/Matrix.hpp:201:102:   required from 'const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>&) const [with T = int]'
    /cygdrive/c/Users/Roy/Desktop/semester s year 1/CPP/ex3/main.cpp:44:31:   required from here
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional:1665:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(const Matrix<int>*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int, int))(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int)>'
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
```

Comment: `addToRow` is static, so remove `std::ref(*this)` from `std::thread`'s arguments list, and turn `_matrix` into `std::ref(_matrix)`. however, `_matrix` is accessed from a const qualified member function, so this will probably fail as well

Comment: `vector` or `Matrix`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: The overhead of spawning and joining a gazillion threads is probably going to dominate.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I suspect they want `ref(result._matrix), ref(other._matrix), ...`